# Why use a promise when making an axios api call?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, es6-promise

I was following a vue.js tutorial and saw something that confuses me and was wondering if someone can explain it to me since I never use promise. The below method is used to assign a customer array object.  Why use a Promise?  I thought Promise should be used when you are returning an object to a service consumer? Why and when should I use a promise?

```
loadCustomer() {
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                axios.get(this.DetailsDataUrl)
                    .then(res => {
                        this.Customer = res.data
                        resolve()
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        console.log(err);
                        reject()
                    })
            });
        }
```

Comment: there is no benefit to wrapping a promise in another promise here. maybe the dev was using the non-promised callback variation of the axios call, in which case it would make a tiny bit of sense, otherwise this is just bad code

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: Is there really no `return` statement in the `loadCustomer` function? If so, the promise is doubly useless, you're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `promises` you can call `asynchronous` functions.
e.g. here when you want to use `loadCustomer` you can `await` until this function resolve or reject:

```
try {
  // resolve
  const response = await loadCustomer()
} catch(err) {
  // reject
  console.log(err)
}
```

`axios` it self return a `promise`:
so you can rewrite your function like this:

```
loadCustoemr() {
  return axios.get(this.DetailsDataUrl)
}
```

and call it:

```
loadCutomer()
  .then(res => this.Customer = res.data)
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

as above you can also use `async/await` here.
for more information you can use [this link](https://javascript.info/promise-basics),